# Where does this quote come from? “How can you say you have no clothes? I’ll share my robe with you”?

Tags: meaning, colloquialisms

Where does it come from? Google can’t help me

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like “豈曰無衣・與子同袍”.

It is from the poem “[無衣](https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=gb&id=15066)” in the *Book of Odes*:

> 豈曰無衣、
>   與子同袍
>
> How shall it be said that you have no clothes?
>   I will share my long robes with you.

Answer (score 2):

The quote is from an ancient Chinese poem collection 诗经（詩經 *the Book of Odes*）. The original full poem is as follows (the quote in question is the first eight characters in the poem):

岂曰无衣？与子同袍。王于兴师，修我戈矛。与子同仇。

岂曰无衣？与子同泽。王于兴师，修我矛戟。与子偕作。

岂曰无衣？与子同裳。王于兴师，修我甲兵。与子偕行。

If you prefer traditional Chinese, below is the same poem in traditional Chinese:

豈曰無衣？與子同袍。王于興師，修我戈矛。與子同仇。

豈曰無衣？與子同澤。王于興師，修我矛繫，與子偕作。

豈曰無衣？與子同裳。王于興師，修我甲兵。與子偕行。

In addition, this quote was particularly popular recently because it was widely used to show friendship during this difficult period that we are all experiencing.